# Páginas restritas conforme permissão de usuário - vuejs / laravel

Tags: vue.js

Como permitir ou impedir que um usuário acesse determinada página? Digamos que o usuário não tenha permissão para acessar a página `finanças`. Onde eu informo na rota do vuejs as permissões de acesso dessa página? Lembrando que essas permissões serão setadas no localStorage oriundas de um backend em laravel.

Comment: Você acha uma boa ideia fazer as validações de permissão no frontend?

Comment: Não. Nem imagino qual seja a melhor solução. Com o laravel puro, eu consigo trabalhar tranquilamente com essas permissões, contudo, agora com o vuejs, separando frontend e backend, não sei como trabalhar essas permissões já que um roda independente do outro. Vi um tutorial no youtube onde, após o login, com o JWT, o backend envia um token para o frontend mas apenas de validação. Ao fazer alguma requisição, o vuejs envie novamente esse token e o backend valida ou não permitindo a execução da operação. Em suma, não sei como autenticar, permitir com laravel e vuejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `beforeEach` do Router ou outro equivalente se estiver utilizando outro router para validar todas as rotas protegidas, conforme a [documentação](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html), para validar o token e as permissões no backend e receber uma resposta simples de autorizado ou não do backend para que o frontend continue a navegação para a rota ou não.

Também pode definir um método `beforeEnter` pra validar uma rota específica:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        // ...
      }
    }
  ]
})
```